# Why does my VBA code work on some file I didn't mention in the code?

Tags: excel, vba

My VBA code is supposed to take a copy of a file, rename it, and keep working on the copied version. It kinda works when I step through, because a copied file, A, would be created, but then my code would not be working on this newly created file A. Instead, it would be working on some file, B, that I haven't opened in days. If I directly run the macro, then A won't even get created. I don't see anywhere in my code mentioning B, but I did copy a big chunk of the code from B. I didn't think that would affect anything because none of my code says anything like "thisworkbook".

```vb
'Dim this conversion tool workbook
Dim wbTool As Workbook
Set wbTool = ThisWorkbook
Dim wsTool As Worksheet
Set wsTool = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)

Dim sMasterLocOld As String, sListLoc As String, sMasterLocNew As String
sMasterLocOld = wsTool.Range("MasterLoc").Value
sListLoc = wsTool.Range("ListLoc").Value
sMasterLocNew = Left(sMasterLocOld, InStr(sMasterLocOld, "_")) + CStr(MonthName(Month(Now), True)) + CStr(Year(Now)) + ".xlsx"
'Copy previous masterfile data onto a new workbook and name it as of current month. All following edits would be based on this new file.
FileCopy sMasterLocOld, sMasterLocNew

'Dim the other two workbooks, and then open them to perform further actions
Dim wbSource As Workbook, wbMapping As Workbook
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(sMasterLocNew)
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Set wbMapping = Workbooks.Open(sListLoc)
Dim wsSource As Worksheet, wsmapping As Worksheet
Set wsSource = wbSource.Sheets(1)
Set wsmapping = wbMapping.Sheets(1)
```

Comment: Can you try to provide a [mcve] and/or a better explanation of what is happening? As currently asked, your problem statement is borderline incoherent. If your code "works" when you step through it, then it should work if you run the macro. It can't possibly "work on a file that you haven't opened in days". That's nonsense. And, BTW, you do reference `ThisWorkbook`, although I don't think that is a problem.

Comment: You have `Set wbTool = ThisWorkbook`, and several other lists to `ThisWorkbook`.  When you wrote ,,but I did copy a big chunk of the code from B", were you saying that the code above was taking from Workbooks("B")?

Comment: Typically there is an issue with not fully qualifying that causes stepping through to give different outputs than just running the code.  Verify your qualifications... it kind of looks like your `sMasterLocNew` can create some type of file due to year and month still providing numbers which can be added.

Comment: @DavidZemens What does making up nonsense benefit me on this forum??What happened was, when i step through, it creates a new file renamed under current month, but doesn't perform anything in the new file, which it should. But when i run the macro, it just opens up that file B, which hasn't been opened by me for a while, and performs actions on B. And i meant none of the code i took from B says anything like "thisworkbook".

Comment: @Cyril Above code wasn't, but the code that I used to perform on wbSource and wbMapping latter on were taken from B.

Comment: What you've provided so far is nowhere near enough to reproduce the problem or to accurately diagnose it or offer much more assistance than what's been offered in the comments. I would ask again that you try to provide a [mcve]. Until and unless you can provide steps to recreate the error condition(s) you describe, there's not much more anyone can offer you.

Comment: *and performs actions on B*??? Since you haven't shown the code that performs any actions, it's impossible to assist.

Comment: *when i run the macro*: **HOW** are you "running" the macro? Is there a hotkey, a commandbar, are you running it from the menu, or from the immediate window, etc?

Comment: Is there any event-driven code in the file(s) you're working with, which might for some reason be opening other workbooks? Are there *references* in either file's VBProject to other workbooks? Etc.

Comment: @DavidZemens I assigned the macro to a button on worksheet, and run by clicking it. I solved the issue, did not change how i assign values to workbook variables, simply added a "save as" instead of save at the end of my code and everything worked. So I guess it wasn't working because it was having trouble saving down the changes, but i still don't understand how file B got opened in the previous tries